# How to build up an object with API calls in componentDidMount to set state

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I am fooling around in React with the Spotify API and I'm having trouble making api calls for nested data.  My plan in componentDidMount was to:

1. fetch user account data
2. use that account data to fetch the user's playlists
3. use those playlists to fetch the tracks in each playlist
4. build up a playlist object which contains name, id, and tracks
5. push the playlist objects to a playlist array
6. set state with user account data and playlist array

Here is my componentDidMount and my method for fetching playlist tracks:

```
    async componentDidMount() {
        const userResponse = await axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.access_token
            }
        });

        const playlistsResponse = await axios.get(
            `https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userResponse.data.id}/playlists`,
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.access_token
                }
            }
        );


        let playlists = [];
        playlistsResponse.data.items.map((playlist) => {
      const tracks = this.getTracks(playlist.id);
            let newPlaylist = {
                name: playlist.name,
                id: playlist.id,
                tracks: tracks
            };
            playlists.push(newPlaylist);
        });

        this.setState({
            playlists: playlists,
            userData: userResponse.data
        });
    }

    async getTracks(playlistID) {
        const tracks = await 
axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlistID}/tracks`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.access_token
            }
        });
        return tracks;
    }
```

After console logging state in render, I see that I was able to set userData in state.  I was also able to set playlists, however, only name and id are passed through, and the tracks are set as Promises.  Am I on the right path in trying to make the tracks API calls inside of map so I can build up my playlist objects 1 at a time?

UPDATE:

So I got it working by assigning my map callback as an async function.  Here is the snippet:

```
        let playlists = [];

        playlistsResponse.data.items.map(async (playlist) => {
            const tracksResponse = await axios.get(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/${playlist.id}/tracks`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.state.access_token
                }
            });

            let newPlaylist = {
                name: playlist.name,
                id: playlist.id,
                tracks: tracksResponse
            };
            playlists.push(newPlaylist);
        });

        this.setState({
            playlists: playlists,
            userData: userResponse.data
        });
    }
```

Is this a fair way of handling this?  To me it makes sense that I am awaiting the tracksResponse data in each iteration of the map before using it later on when building up my playlist object.  Is it safe/common practice to wrap my map callback in async/await?

UPDATE 2:

Ok maybe it didn't work.  I can see everything in state when I check Chrome devtools, but when I try to render what's in state nothing is spit out.

Comment: `setState` is async in nature. 

You need to wait for `tracks` to get fetched before you do `setState`.

Comment: But how do I wait for tracks to get fetched?  I thought since I made getTracks an async function it would wait for the tracks to get fetched before returning them each time it is called in my map.

Comment: You need to change the order of functions. 
Move `setState` at last. 

Also store the response of `tracks` as you have done with playlist and userReposne.
Would be easier to read. 
Like so: `const tracksResponse = await getTracks`

Comment: setState is last inside of componentDidMount, getTracks is a method I've defined outside of componentDidMount

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding async await. For instance, in your function `getTracks`, async await will be used to return after the fetch is resolved. It doesn't work as a callback

Comment: ah yes. 
But `getTracks` is an `async` function. That is why you are getting an array of promises in `tracks`.

You can do `await Promise.all(tracks).`

Comment: I edited it. try to receive from maps

Answer (score 0):

You probably is setState before you resolve your map. I'd suggest you to use a `Promise.all`, like so:

```
let playlists = [];
    const map = playlistsResponse.data.items.map((playlist) => {
  const tracks = this.getTracks(playlist.id);
        let newPlaylist = {
            name: playlist.name,
            id: playlist.id,
            tracks: tracks
        };
        playlists.push(newPlaylist);
    });

   await Promise.all(map);

    this.setState({
        playlists: playlists,
        userData: userResponse.data
    });
```